# Select Nested Json Column based on condition from json_table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have Json like

```
{
  Col1:Test,
  Col2: [
      nestedCol1:"Test",
      nestedCol2: [
          toSelect:"Value"
      ],
      nestedCol3: [
          toSelect:"Value1"
      ]
]
}
```

I have to select `toSelect` Value Columns, based on some condition.
If condition is true, then selected `nestedCol2` value, otherwise select `nestedCol3` value.
both Nested Columns `nestedCol2` and `nestedCol3`, will have same column names inside.

I have sql

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM   Table d,
       json_table (
         d.json,
         '$'
         columns (
           nested Col2[*] columns (
             nestedCol1,
             nested nestedCol2[*] columns (
               toSelect
             )
           )
         )
       )
```

Comment: Your JSON is not valid syntax as there are no quotes around keys or string values and `[]` brackets around key-value pairs. Also, your SQL is invalid as there is no `j` table alias.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to select `toSelect` Value Columns, based on some condition. If condition is true, then selected `nestedCol2` value, otherwise select `nestedCol3` value.

Select all the columns and then filter in the `SELECT` clause using a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN c2_nc1 = 'Test'
       THEN c2_nc2_ts
       ELSE c2_nc3_ts
       END AS to_select
FROM   table_name d,
       json_table (
         d.json,
         '$'
         columns (
           c2_nc1   VARCHAR2(30) PATH '$.Col2.nestedCol1',
           c2_nc2_ts VARCHAR2(30) PATH '$.Col2.nestedCol2.toSelect',
           c2_nc3_ts VARCHAR2(30) PATH '$.Col2.nestedCol3.toSelect'
         )
       ) j
```

Which, for the (fixed) sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (json JSON);

INSERT INTO table_name (json)
SELECT '{
  "Col1":"Test",
  "Col2": {
      "nestedCol1":"Test",
      "nestedCol2": {"toSelect":"Value"},
      "nestedCol3": {"toSelect":"Value1"}
  }
}' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | TO_SELECT |
> | --- |
> | Value |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=43e01e841a3f7d180ce5eb8f170de5a1)*

Comment: I have to select multiple columns values, not only just one attribute "toSelect", nested columns contains 20 attributes which i have to select.

Comment: @Karan Do exactly the same for 20 attributes that you would do for 2; select all 20 attributes in the `JSON_TABLE` and use `CASE` expressions to pick which ones you want based on the conditions you want to use (but the question does not mention any more attributes or conditions so you have an answer for what you gave us).